# Regarding a function continuous at a point and an interval surrounding it

Tags: real-analysis

I'm given the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous at $x_0$ and that $f(x_0)>0$. I need to prove by contradiction that there is an interval $I=(x_0-1/n, x_0+1/n)$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in I$.

I drew a little sketch of what I'm looking at and can tell that it has to be true, otherwise with a sufficiently small interval $f$ wouldn't be continuous, but I'm struggling with putting together what I have and need to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x_0) > 0$ means that $f(x_0) \in (0,\infty)$, which is an open set. By the definition of continuity, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$, $f(x) \in (0,\infty)$; i.e. $f(x) > 0$. Then just take $n$ large enough so that $1/n < \delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon(>0)=\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$ be considered.
Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ so corresponding to given $\epsilon$ $\exists \delta >0$ such that $\forall x \in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta) $

$|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

$\implies \frac{f(x_0)}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3f(x_0)}{2}$

By archimedean property corresponding to $\delta>0 \exists n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\delta >\frac{1}{n}$

Hence $\forall x \in (x_0-\frac{1}{n},x_0+\frac{1}{n}) $

$f(x)>0$